# Disabling Spring Boot 2 Autocommit Hikari

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, autocommit

I am using hikari connection pool with JPA hibernate. I want to disable autocommit feature during read operations while interacting with DB.

Added
`spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false` property. After adding this property in `application.properties`, getting the below error during startup.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) failed:

    Property: spring.datasource.hikari.autoCommit
    Value: false
    Reason: Property 'autoCommit' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration of the pool is sealed once started. Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes.


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Hikari version: 3.2.0

Springboot verison : 1.5.14-RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following Hibernate config:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        connection:
          provider_disables_autocommit: true
```

More information regarding this setting can be found in [Vlad Mihalcea's blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/).

Comment: Since I am using spring boot 1.5.14.Release, the hibernate version is 5.0.12. I can see from your blog that from Hibernate 5.2.10 only that property will be applicable. Is there any alternative for hibernate 5.0.12 version?

Comment: @venkat that is very unfortunate, sorry! Is updating your dependency versions no option? I don't know about a means for an older Hibernate version.

Comment: I have upgraded to hibernate 5.4.12, and added property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true in application.properties. But in hibernate logs I still see [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing